# Where does in ext3 source code requests to read an indirect block sent?

Tags: linux-kernel, ext3

i want to find that place and set a flag in that request so i can identify these requests in block io layer.
i changed bio structure and add an extra flag and i want to set this flag for all indirect block requests which sent to disk.

Answer (score 2):

I believe  what you are looking for is 
the call to `ext3_get_branch` in **/fs/ext3/inode.c** is what you are looking for.
which reads the chain of indirect blocks leading to data.

The call trace up to the read syscall is as follows:
**/fs/ext3/inode.c**

`ext3_get_branch` is called by `ext3_get_blocks_handle`

`ext3_get_blocks_handle` is called by `ext3_get_block`

`ext3_get_block` is passed as function pointer to be called by `mpage_readpage` in **/fs/mpage.c** by `ext3_readpage`

**/mm/filemap.c**

`ext3_readpage` is called by  `mapping->a_ops->readpage(filp, page);` in `do_generic_file_read`

`do_generic_file_read` is called by `generic_file_aio_read`

**/fs/read_write.c**

`generic_file_aio_read` is called by ``` ret = filp->f_op->aio_read(&kiocb, &iov, 1, kiocb.ki_pos);`` in ```do_sync_read`where` filp->f_op->aio_read`is the  function pointer of`generic_file_aio_read` defined in **/fs/ext3/inode.c**

`do_sync_read` is mapped to the `read` system call in the struct definition of `generic_ro_fops`.